# Localize workflow task title in alfresco activiti

Tags: localization, workflow, alfresco, activiti

I followed this tutorial to create a custom alfresco activiti workflow: http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/workflow/tutorial/tutorial.html

I tried to externalize the contained strings by creating `.properties` files and made them known in the `xyz-context.xml`. While this is working I face a problem with changing the title of a worfklow task.

**I use the following sampleWorkflow.properties file:**

```
 sampleWf.task.confirmTask.title=Confirm this, with a title which is different than the task name
 sampleWf.task.confirmTask.description=Confirm please
```

**The bpmn-snippet for this tasks, is configured like this:**

```
<userTask id="confirmTask" name="Confirm" activiti:assignee="${bpm_assignee.properties.userName}" activiti:formKey="samplewf:customTypeTask"></userTask>
```

### My question is

Why only the description of the workflow tasks change, but not the title?

The above localization works, when I don't use the task ID but it's property like this:

```
sampleWf.task.samplewf_customTypeTask.title=This changes the title
```

If this the only possibility I'd need to deploy a lot of custom types just for naming purposes. Can't I reuse types across workflows and just change the title (name) by this configuration?

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to [this link](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/WorkflowAdministration#Step_4:_Create_Workflow_Resource_Bundles) in order to have a better idea on how strings could be localized in a workflow in Alfresco :

> ```
> <workflow_prefix>_<workflow_name>.workflow.[title|description]
> <workflow_prefix>_<workflow_name>.node.<node_name>.[title|description]
> <workflow_prefix>_<workflow_name>.node.<node_name>.transition.<transition_name>.[title|description]
> <workflow_prefix>_<workflow_name>.task.<task_prefix>_<task_name>.[title|description]
> ```

where:

> ```
> <workflow_prefix> is the workflow model namespace prefix
> <workflow_name> is the workflow name
> <node_name> is the name of a node within the workflow
> <transition_name> is the name of a node transition within the workflow
> <task_prefix> is the task namespace prefix
> <task_name> is the task name
> <transition_name> is the workflow transition name
> ```

Which suggests you should be putting something like :

```
sampleWf_<workflow-name>.task.sampleWf_confirmTask.title=Confirm this, with a title which is different than the task name
```

Which -in theory- should give you the possibility of using the same task model in multiple workflows with different localization, but I guess you still have to duplicate your model in order to be able to have multiple localizations in the same workflow!

**Update :**
Oops! I got tricked by this statement:

> This page was last modified on 13 March 2015, at 02:22.

That was a bot marking the page as obsolete!
The page is obviously outdated and it is talking about jbpm, not activiti, hopefully you still can use the same naming conventions!

**Otherwise**, worst case scenario, you got to create new task models that basically just extend your original task model to be able to customize the task title as needed (No need to redefine properties/constraints ...).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think the documentation is out of date here since it seems to address the jbpm implementation only. This is still an interesting link though. I dug through the [alfresco git](https://github.com/Alfresco/community-edition/blob/master/projects/repository/config/alfresco/workflow/workflow-messages.properties) only to find that the word `node` only seem to be a thing within jbpm but not activiti. Please correct me if I'am wrong. Your assumption is correct, you can change the title using the type as task reference (which is very inconsistent imho)...

Comment: You are absolutely right!
I got tricked by the modification date at the end of the page, sorry for that! But,  hopefully you still can use the same naming conventions!

Otherwise, worst case scenario, you got to create new task models that basically **just extend your original task model** to be able to customize the task title as needed (No need to redefine properties/constraints ...).

Comment: No need to apologize, thank you very much for your input :). The docs can be really confusing some times. Yes, the only possibility (as it seems) is to create custom types for each workflow using `<parent>` in the model definition to make it somehow not to ugly. I'am still hoping for a better solution. Thank you again